# Flex Bootstrap 5 whem resizing form to small, set divs to full width

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-5

After resizing the form to small, the divs do wrap verticaly but how to make the divs resize to full width?. I have tried different approachs, like flex-fill and flex-grow-1

```
<div style="">
    <EditForm Model="model">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="d-flex flex-sm-wrap">
                <div class=""><InputText @bind-Value="model.Name" /></div>
                <div class=""><InputText @bind-Value="model.EMailAddress" /></div>
                <div class=""><InputText @bind-Value="model.Address" /></div>
                <div class=""><InputText @bind-Value="model.Phone" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
</div>


@code {
    Model model = new Model();

    public class Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EMailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"flex-row flex-sm-column"` should switch from row to column layout on small

Comment: Didn't work for me :(